# Use of 'median' function in calculated field in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, aggregate-functions, mdx

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345330%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) it looks like you can use an aggregate function in a calculated field, but if I try and use the median command, I get an error
"the value expression for the field =Median( ...what I wrote below..) contains an error: BC30451 Name 'Median' is not declared.

I have tried

```
=Median(Fields!name_of_field_I_want_median_from.Value,"dsTheDatasetFieldIsIn")
```

and

```
=Median(Fields!name_of_field_I_want_median_from.Value)
```

neither work

N.B. Dataset is derived from MDX

Answer (score 2):

maybe I didn't understand your post, but I think that you use incorrect syntax. Try use [next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145570.aspx) syntax:

```
Median(Set_Expression [ ,Numeric_Expression ] ),
```

where Numeric_Expression --- it's your measure.

P.S. Also, you can post full expression of your calculated member.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Median is not an SSRS function , or it does not work inside an aggregate on an SSRS dataset.

**My simple workaround** if you are stuck with SSRS.

1. Create a Bar Chart with the data set you're investigating .
2. Add a calculated set to the chart (and you can pick Median or Mean or any
   other stat).
3. Select to "show data label" on the Median set show
   exact number.

Best of Luck.